# If the points $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are distinct,then...

Tags: numerical-methods

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> If the points $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are distinct,then for arbitrary real values $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$, prove that the degree of the unique interpolating polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(x_i)=y_i,\,\,(1 \le i \le n)$ is $\le n-1$.

I think I have to use [Lagrange polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) but I could not put the things together . Can someone help? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As currently worded, the assertion is false. There are infinitely many interpolating polynomials, of arbitrarily high degrees. For if $P(x)$ is an interpolating polynomial, so is 
$$P(x)+Q(x)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$$
for any polynomial $Q(x)$.

What we can say is that there is a unique interpolating polynomial of degree $\le n-1$.

To prove that, we need to do two things (i) show that there is an interpolating polynomial of degree $\le n-1$ and (ii) show that there is at most one.

For (i) use the ordinary Lagrange polynomial.

For (ii), suppose that $P$ and $Q$ are interpolating polynomials of degree $\le n-1$, Then $P-Q$ is $0$ at $x_1,x_2 ,\dots,x_n$. But a polynomial of degree $\le n-1$ can have $n$ or more distinct roots only if it is the identically $0$ polynomial. It follows that $P-Q$ is identically $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think it little bit differently. Such a polynomial exists uniquely if you try to see it as follows.

Take $y_i = f(x_i)$ for $ i = 1, 2, \dots, n$. $f$ is a function whose analytical formula is unknown.

Take interpolation polynomial $L_{n-1}(x)$ of degree $n-1$ s.t. $L_n(x_i) = f(x_i)$ for $i= 1, 2,\dots,n$.

Write $L_{n-1}(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_{n-1} x^{n-1}$

Thus $a_0 + a_1x_i + \dots + a_{n-1}x_i^{n-1} = f(x_i)$

Put different values of $i = 1, 2, \dots,n$ and put $f(x_i) = y_i$ which are known.

You shall get $(n)$ linear equation with $(n)$ unknowns $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}$.

The determinant of the corresponding matrix is Vandermonde's determinant with non zero value.

So the values of coefficients can be determined uniquely i.e. the interpolation polynomial will find out uniquely

Comment: You do not require to use Lagrenges polynomial for existance and uniqueness.